# unable to match document containing all words specified in query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am struggling to get only those documents which contains **word1** and **word2** both at least. I tried multiple ways to form request but still fails to fetch required records. Below request returns document even if **word1** is missing from document but it contains **word2**.

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "source": "source1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "qty": "1"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "product_name": {
                            "query": "word1 word2",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting fuzziness "0" ? Would be good if you could show the docs that are matching (and you dont expect them too)

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

There are many ways to achieve this.
Either with a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query for keywords type fields or [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) for text fields.

## Solution

Assuming the field `product_name` is of type text.

```json
POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"74018346"}}
{"product_name":"This sentence has word1 and word2"}
{"index":{"_index":"74018346"}}
{"product_name":"this sentence only has word1"}
{"index":{"_index":"74018346"}}
{"product_name":"in this one, only word2 is present"}
{"index":{"_index":"74018346"}}
{"product_name":"None of the words are presents"}


GET 74018346/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "word1 AND word2",
      "default_field": "product_name"
    }
  }
}
```